# MySQL return values count

Tags: mysql, count, group-by, concatenation, database-table

I have a fairly boggling problem. What I'm after is a list of all the industries whether they have been linked to a job or not. So..

```
Web Design [0]
Accounts[3]
Sales[1]
Marketing[0]
```

So that the jobs in the database have a industry id that's saved with the job. the industry table has a list of industry types. 
Web Design, Accounts, Sales, Marketing etc
Below is my SQL so far

```
SELECT ind.name,ind.id, GROUP_CONCAT(job.industry_id) AS id,
COUNT(*) AS industry_count
FROM jobs AS job,
industries AS ind
WHERE ind.id = job.industry_id
GROUP BY industry_id
```

This returns the count of each job that belongs to an industry but i want all industries to be returned with or without jobs linked to them.
Thank you all so much for helping. Rob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you need a `LEFT JOIN`. Try this out:

```
SELECT ind.name, ind.id,
  COALESCE(GROUP_CONCAT(job.industry_id), 'default_value') AS id,
  COUNT(job.industry_id) AS industry_count
FROM industries ind
LEFT JOIN jobs job ON ind.id = job.industry_id
GROUP BY ind.id
```

Note if there is no job for a given industry you'll get `null` in the GROUP_CONCAT. You can add a default value for those cases that way.

Comment: Yes, thanks. But now the count is returning 1 for all the null entries. What am i missing. thank you for your help

Comment: Yes, so we get...for example sales [0]

Comment: You are a star. Thank you so much. Have a great weekend